# (Micropython) Creating and comparing time objects

Tags: time, micropython

Using Micropython for the ESP32 microcontroller, flashed with the latest firmware at time of writing (v1.18)

I'm making an alarm (sort-of) system where I get multiple time values ("13:15" for example) from my website, and then I have to ring an alarm bell at those times.

I've done the website and I can do the ring stuff, but I don't know how to actually create time objects from the previously mentioned strings ("13:15"), and then check if any of the times inputted match the current time, **the date is irrelevant**.

From reading the documentation, im getting the sense that this cant be done, since ive looked through the [micropython module github](https://github.com/micropython/micropython-lib), and you apparently cant get **datetime** in micropython, and i know that in regular python my problem can be solved with **datetime**.

```py
import ntptime
import time
import network

# Set esp as a wifi station
station = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
# Activate wifi station
station.active(True)
# Connect to wifi ap
station.connect(ssid,passwd)
while station.isconnected() == False:
        print('.')
        time.sleep(1)
print(station.ifconfig())
try:
        print("Local time before synchronization: %s" %str(time.localtime()))
        ntptime.settime()
        print("Local time after synchronization: %s" %str(time.localtime()))
    except:
        print("Error syncing time, exiting...")
```

this is the shortened code from my project, with only the time parts, now comes into play the time comparison thing I don't know how to do.

Comment: According to [the docs](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/time.html#module-time) you should be able to use `time.mktime` - does that work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ntptime to get time from server. I use "time.google.com", to get the time. Then, I transform it into seconds (st) to be more accurate. And set my targets hour in seconds 1 hour = 3600 s.

```
import utime
import ntptime

def server_time():
    try:
        # Ask to time.google.com server the current time.
        ntptime.host = "time.google.com"
        ntptime.settime()
        t = time.localtime()
        # print(t)
        # transform tuple time 't' to seconds value. 1 hour = 
        st = t[3]*3600 + t[4]*60 + t[5]
        return st  
    except:
        # print('no time')
        st = -1
        return st 


while True:
      # Returns an increasing millisecond counter since the Board reset.
      now = utime.ticks_ms()

      # Check current time every 5000 ms (5s) without going to sleep or stop any other process.
      if now >= period + 5000:
          period += 5000
          
          # call your servertime function
          st = server_time()
              if  ((st > 0) and (st < 39600)) or (st > 82800):    # Turn On 17:00 Mexico Time.
                    # something will be On between 17:00 - 06:00
              elif ((st <82800) and (st > 39600)):                # Turn Off 6:00.
                  # something will be Off between 06:00 - 17:00
              else:
                  pass
```

Answer (score 0):

After running ntptime.settime() you can do the following to retrieve the time, keep in mind this is in UTC:

```
rtc = machine.RTC()
hour = rtc.datetime()[4] if (rtc.datetime()[4]) > 9 else "0%s" % rtc.datetime()[4]
minute = rtc.datetime()[5] if rtc.datetime()[5] > 9 else "0%s" % rtc.datetime()[5]
```

The if else statement makes sure that numbers lower or equal to 9 are padded with a zero.